# Pandas: How to loc[] by MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a strange mistake in my code. 
What I generally want to do is to get a part of DataFrame table by MultiIndex

[DataFrame be like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXLCe.png)

```
more_than_one_race = df.groupby(['department', 'position'])['Pay Rate'].count()
more_than_one_race = more_than_one_race[more_than_one_race > 1].index
df.loc[more_than_one_race]
```

And I got the following error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,2) (3,) (3,2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem MutliIndex has 3 levels and you want filter by 2 levels MultiIndex, so levels numbers not matched, so error is raised.

Better is use here [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
ser = df.groupby(['department', 'position'])['Pay Rate'].transform('count')

df.loc[ser > 1]
```